# получить часть содержимого блока по селектору

Tags: html, jquery

добрый день. есть такая структура разметки:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item1">...</div>
<div class="item2">...</div>
<div class="item3">...</div>
</div>
```

как получить `html()` конкретного `item`, но с родительским блоком? т.е. сейчас `$(this).html()` вернёт мне `...`, а мне надо получить `<div class="item1">...</div>`, как это сделать? (есть возможность js`ом нарисовать родительский блок, но вдруг могут понадобиться атрибуты блока, интересует конструкция получения такого блока)

Comment: [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Comment: спасибо, ваш комментарий навёл меня на одну статью, там оказался способ проще: $(".item1").get(0)

Comment: метод `get` возвращает сам HTMLElement, а не разметку(строку) - в вопросе ему соответствует `this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">...</div>
    <div class="item2">...</div>
    <div class="item3">...</div>
</div>
<script>
    alert($('.item1').get(0).outerHTML);
</script>
```

`.get()` возвращает массив найденных значений.

`.get(0)` - забирает первый элемент массива - объект jQuery.

`.outerHTML` - возвращает полный HTML элемента, включая содержимое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.